# Cannot apply for job

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was filling out a job application and when I click the apply button after filling out the application, it takes me to a page that says "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

I retried the application several times with the same result each time. I would like to apply for this job but I'm not able to right now.

Comment: Looking into this right now...

Comment: Can you try to apply and re-upload your resumé again?

Comment: I keep getting the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report. There was a cache entry associated with your application that had invalid data on it. I've cleaned up the state and you should be good to go. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I was able to apply for this job after this message. Thanks!